# Most concise way to parse JSON with JSON.NET, without

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

Let's say I have this JSON:

```
{
  "top.level": {
    "mykey": "3.301.0.97",
    "mykey2": "not interested in this one"
  },
  "another.top.level": "not interested in this either"
}
```

I'm looking to use Json.NET to parse this string, and get the value of of "mykey".

I have two questions:

1. How can I do this *without* strong typing in C#, while gracefully handling scenarios where the JSON doesn't have `top.level` or `mykey`? I don't want to end up throwing NullReferenceExceptions or similar. Is there a more elegant answer than below?

```
string answer;
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

if (jsonObj != null)
{
   var topElement = jsonObj["top.level"];
   if (topElement != null)
   {
      var keyElement = topElement["mykey"];
      if (keyElement != null)
      {
         answer = keyElement.Value<string>();
      }
    }
}
```

2. Let's say I *do* want to use strong typing. How do I do this, considering the presence of the period in `top.level`? What type definition would I create, considering I'm ignoring `mykey2` and `another.top.level`?

I'm also open to doing both of these things without using Json.NET, using any of .NET's built-in serialization mechanisms, so all ideas and suggestions welcome. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "elegant?"  If your example feels too messy, hide it in a method.

Comment: You could also try something like `jsonObj["top.level"]?.topElement["mykey"]?.Value<string>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use null propagation to make your code more readable. For instance, the following code could replace your example:

```
var answer = jsonObj?["top.level"]?.Value<string>("myKey");
```

For your second question, you can use `JsonProperty` attribute to define a custom name for the property. This could represent your example:

```
public class Level2 { public string MyKey { get; set; } }
public class Level1
{
    [JsonProperty("top.level")]
    public Level2 TopLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can deserialize with this code:

```
var strongType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Level1>(str);
var answer = strongType?.TopLevel?.MyKey;
```